# Drawing a class multiple times on the screen XNA

Tags: xna, xna-4.0, spritebatch

I am making a simple brick-breaker type game. I have a ball paddle class, and i have both moving around the screen fine. I also have a brick class, of a brick, that when it is hit with the ball it dissapears. Now i want multiple bricks on the screen without manually drawing them all by writing

> spriteBatch.Draw(brickTexture, brickPosition, Color.White);

Over and over. (With differant positions). How do i draw the class multiple times and each brick be able to dissapear when it is hit.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how long have you been programming C#?

Answer (score 0):

During initialization, you can make an array of `Brick` to contain all instances of your bricks:

```
Brick[] bricks = new Brick[num_bricks];
for(int i=0; i<num_bricks; i++) 
    bricks[i] = new Brick();
```

Then you can use a `foreach` loop to draw them all:

```
foreach(Brick br in bricks) 
    spriteBatch.Draw(brickTexture, br.position, Color.White);
```

Comment: i did this but i am getting an error saying "Object reference not set to an instance of an object". What should i do?

Comment: After you make the array, you'll have to initialize each `Brick` in `bricks` before you can use them: `for(int i=0; i<num_bricks; i++) {bricks[i] = new Brick():}`

Comment: Also, you should put braces around your loops:
`for(int i=0; i<num_bricks; i++)
{
    bricks[i] = new Brick();
}`
and 
`foreach(Brick br in bricks) 
{
    spriteBatch.Draw(brickTexture, br.position, Color.White);
}`
It doesn't change how it compiles, but it makes future programmers not rage at the bad practices.